# Scheduler in MultiThreading environment

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel, scheduling

How many scheduler might find in a Operating System with Multithreading?
I'm not sure of the answer, but I think it depends on whether you work with kernel-level threads or user level, I hope you can help me clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Any number of schedulers you want your system to have. DOS pretty much had zero, the Linux kernel usually has one (process) scheduler, though there are other types of scheds, and finally, userspace programs can do whatever they want, so there may be any number of (process) schedulers. Especially considering cron and LSF.

Comment: I refer to process scheduler, I think the number of process scheduler depends on whether the threads are executed at the kernel level or user. but im really not sure. excuse my english.